# Rendering HTML from map function in React Context API render function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx, map-function, react-context

I'm trying to render out a list of titles by calling map on state from inside the `<MyContext.Consumer>` component but the code is not returning the list items. However, if I do a `console.log(dataImTryingToMap);` it shows exactly what I'm trying to render. The `<ul>` is rendered but no `<li>`'s are. There are no errors   thrown by create-react-app. What am I missing??? Here is the consumer component:

```
<MyContext.Consumer>
    {context => (
        <ul>
            {Object.keys(context.state.subjects).map(subject => {
                <li>{context.state.subjects[subject].title}</li>;
                console.log(context.state.subjects[subject].title);
             })}
        </ul>
    )}
</MyContext.Consumer>
```

The console log returns exactly the data I'm looking for, but nothing shows on the screen.

And here is the state from the `<MyContext.MyProvider>` component:

```
state = {
    subjects: {
        subject0: {
            title: "Math",
            description: "",
            cards: {
                card1: {
                    note: "",
                    answer: ""
                }
            }
        },
        subject1: {
            title: "history",
            description: "",
            cards: {
                card1: {
                    note: "",
                    answer: ""
                }
            }
        }
    }
};
```

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not returning anything from the `Array.map()` callback:

```
{Object.keys(context.state.subjects).map(subject => {
    <li>{context.state.subjects[subject].title}</li>; <-- this is not returned
    console.log(context.state.subjects[subject].title);
 })}
```

```js
const contextValue = { state: {"subjects":{"subject0":{"title":"Math","description":"","cards":{"card1":{"note":"","answer":""}}},"subject1":{"title":"history","description":"","cards":{"card1":{"note":"","answer":""}}}}}};


const MyContext = React.createContext();

const Example = () => (
  <MyContext.Consumer>
  {context => (
    <ul>
    {Object.keys(context.state.subjects).map(subject => {
      console.log(context.state.subjects[subject].title);
      return (
        <li key={subject}>{context.state.subjects[subject].title}</li>
      );
     })}
    </ul>
  )}
  </MyContext.Consumer>
);

const Demo = ({ value }) => (
  <MyContext.Provider value={value}>
    <Example />
  </MyContext.Provider>
);

ReactDOM.render(
  <Demo value={contextValue} />,
  demo
);
```

```html
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@16.3/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16.3/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>

<div id="demo">
  </demo>
```

Comment: the implicit return or adding "return" keyword doesn't change anything (i'll update my code, I was implicitly returning the <li> before posting).

Comment: on inspecting the page, the <MyContext.Consumer> element, along with the <ul> inside of it is rendered, but no <li>'s

Comment: The demo is working, as you can see. So, find the differences between the demo and your code.

Comment: In a test, I do get the data I want rendered if I write in the consumer component: <p>{context.state.subjects.subject0.title}</p>

renders "Math" to the page

Comment: yes yes yes, in doing more testing I had changed the 'map' to a 'forEach' and forgotten to change it back. too many late nights coding....Thank you!

Comment: Good to hear :)

Answer (score 0):

You haven't returned anything from inside the map function and hence it doesn't render anything. Either return it explicitly like

```
<MyContext.Consumer>
    {context => (
        <ul>
            {Object.keys(context.state.subjects).map(subject => {
                return <li>{context.state.subjects[subject].title}</li>;
             })}
        </ul>
    )}
</MyContext.Consumer>
```

or implicitly like

```
<MyContext.Consumer>
    {context => (
        <ul>
            {Object.keys(context.state.subjects).map(subject => (
                 <li>{context.state.subjects[subject].title}</li>;
            ))}
        </ul>
    )}
</MyContext.Consumer>
```

Comment: the implicit return or adding "return" keyword doesn't change anything (i'll update my code, I was implicitly returning the <li> before posting.